# PostgreSQL Entity Framework error

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework

I have a model

```
public class Role
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string shortname { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string login { get; set; }
    public int idrole { get; set; }
    public DateTime regdate { get; set; }
    public int idregistred { get; set; }
    public virtual Role role { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm create the repository and load data:

```
 public class Repository
    {
        public  IQueryable<TEntity> Select<TEntity>()
           where TEntity : class
        {
            var context = new QContext();
            return context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

    }

 var rep = new Repository();
 var roles = rep.Select<User>().Include(el => el.role).ToList();
```

When I load the data, I have error:

> column Extent1.role_id does not exist

Generated SQL:

> SELECT "Extent1"."id", "Extent1"."login", "Extent1"."idrole",
>   "Extent1"."regdate", "Extent1"."idregistred", "Extent2"."id" AS "id1",
>   "Extent2"."name", "Extent2"."shortname" FROM "questionnaire"."user" AS
>   "Extent1" LEFT OUTER JOIN "questionnaire"."role" AS "Extent2" ON
>   "Extent1"."role_id" = "Extent2"."id"

But in database I have not column "role_id". In "questionnaire"."user" I have only "idrole".

How I can load the data? Why entity create incorrect sql code? How fix it?

I use entity framework v6.1.3, Npgsql v2.2.7 and Npgsql.EntityFramework v2.2.7

Comment: Adding attribute `[ForeignKey("idrole")]` to the definition of `role` in class `User`would help?

Comment: Have error The property 'idrole' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type.

Comment: That's ok! Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework can't guess how you have linked the tables to each other. The default way is adding `_id` to the field name, which results in `role_id`. You have to tell EF what the actual column is for it to work. You can do this by using `ForeignKeyAttribute`:

```
[ForeignKey("idrole")]
public Role role { get; set; }
```

This way EF knows the column `idrole` is used to reference the `role` table.